# remove level from a list extract to a data fram

Tags: r, dataframe, levels

I have a data frame like this

```
    df <- data.frame(letters=letters[1:5], numbers=seq(1:5))
```

and lets say that I want to extram the first column into a list

```
firstColumn <- df[,1]

>  firstColumn[[1]]
[1] a
Levels: a b c d e
```

Problème is I want to remove the level to have a string

any help please ?

thanks

Comment: There is no list in your question. `firstColumn` is a vector. In your own interest you should learn proper terminology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question, you're trying to convert to character.

Try

```
as.character(firstColumn[[1]])
```

Answer (score 6):

Either define your variable as character from the beginning :

```
df <- data.frame(letters=letters[1:5], numbers=seq(1:5), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Or convert it afterwards :

```
firstColumn <- as.character(df[,1])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list but without levels, first import the column of your dataframe as a vector and then turn it into a list. Here the one-liner:

```
firstColumn_list <- as.list(as.vector(df[,1]))
```

You could also use the `drop.levels` function from the package `gdata`:

```
firstColumn_list <- as.list(df[,1])
firstColumn_list_wo_levels <- gdata::drop.levels(firstColumn_list)
```